# Query logging for mySQL on shared server

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I have a VPS with Dreamhost but the mySQL server is shared.  I really want to start producing accessible logs of every mySQL query a particular site issues.

I can hand roll this into my abstraction layer but I was curious is there was something like sql_log_off that can be set at runtime so all queries get logged into files I can rotate and review?

Comment: You might be as well interested in the statistics the mysqlnd driver offers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.stats.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of what the question is asking:
What you could do is wrap your queries into some sort of wrapper that logs the queries into a file. This could be a text file or a PHP file that will only allow those with permission to view (a log viewer script could include this so that only those with proper access can view).

That is of course saying if you are able to do so. (If you are wanting to log queries from sites that you have no control over then I am not sure.)

An example of a wrapper you might be interested in:

```
   function sql_query($query, $show=0)
    {
     global $queries, $debugginglist;
     $thequery = mysql_query($query) or print(mysql_error()."<br>Query was: <code>".htmlspecialchars($query)."</code>");
     $queries++;

    if ($show == 1)
     {
      print "($queries): Query was: <i><code>".htmlspecialchars($query)."</code></i><br>";
     }

     $debugginglist .= "$qbr($queries): Query was: <i><code>$query</code></i><br>";


     //this is just to give an idea for logging, NOT an exact solution
     $logquery = fopen("querylog.txt", "ab+");
     fputs($logquery, "\r\n$query");
     fclose($logquery);

     return $thequery;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is, in fact, what I ended up doing.  I should have updated the post.  I use a PHP abstraction layer I made myself and I added a logging routine to all querying routines and added a global with various levels to control what degree of logging is desired.